# Can Piecewise Regression Method of Jean Jacquelin be extended to 4 segments?

Tags: regression, piecewise-linear

I want to identify the matris form of general y=f(x) function for:
y(x)=p1x+q1 x<a1
=p2x+q2 x<a2
=p3x+q3 x<a3
=p4x+q4 x>a3
where a1,a2,a3,p1,q1,p2,q2,p3,q3,p4,q4 are unknown parameters to be approximately computed in paper : https://fr.scribd.com/document/380941024/Regression-par-morceaux-Piecewise-Regression-pdf